# SchemaSpy on Mac for SQLite

Tags: macos

I know Java ok, but not heavy.  I am trying to get SchemaSpy working on a MAC to look at an SQLITE database.  Everything find except for....

```
Failed to load driver 'SQLite.JDBCDriver'from: < either one below >
```

I have the following files in the classpath / -cp / -classpath with no luck

```
 sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
 sqlitejdbc-v056.jar
```

Neither of these seem to have the SQLite.JDBCDriver class when unpacked.

The command line is...

```
 java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t sqlite -o output -u admin -db db.sqlite -dp sqlitejdbc-v056.jar
```

full output is....

```
Using database properties:
  [schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar]/net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/sqlite.properties
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SQLite.JDBCDriver

Failed to load driver 'SQLite.JDBCDriver'from: [file:/Users/rudyyukich/Desktop/ss/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar]
This entry doesn't point to a valid file/directory: [sqlite.jar]

Use the -dp option to specify the location of the database drivers for your database (usually in a .jar or .zip/.Z).
```

Can't seem to get past this driver issue.

Yes I have tried CLASSPATH, etc with the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up getting it to work under windows, but had to do the following

1) Create a properties file with the following (sqlite2.properties)

```
description=SQLite2

connectionSpec=jdbc:sqlite:<db>
db=path to database or :memory:

driver=org.sqlite.JDBC

# Sample path to the SQLite drivers.
# Use -dp to override.
driverPath=sqlite.jar
```

2) Download the drivers above and copy one to sqlite.jar

3) Download and install the Graphviz 2.2.1 version (has to be this on windows at least)

4) Run the command line like

```
java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t sqlite2 -u admin -db ./db.sqlite -dp sqlite.jar  -o output -gv "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\"

where 
-jar is the jar file for the schemaSpy
-t is the type of database, in our case the properties file
-u username is needed, can be anything I guess
-db is the database to be scanned
-dp is the jar filename of the driver renamed above
-o is the output directory
-gv is the location of the graphviz installation, in this case on windows
```

If I get this working on MAC, will also post

Hope this helps.

Generates pretty good HTML scan of the database.